# Font rendering blurry in browser

Tags: web-fonts, blur, anti-aliasing, subpixel-rendering, browser

So hopefully this is the right form for this question.

I'm not much of a designer however on a site I'm working on, I noticed that on my "404" page, the text appears blurry on chrome, and a lot more crisp in firefox.

Top being Firefox, Bottom being Chrome.

[image]

I've tried different font format types, the current image is using "woff2" however the error seems to persist regardless of the type.

I was going to try SVG font however that appears to no longer be available in Chrome.

I've attempted to use the `-webkit-font-smoothing` and all of its various options, but none of them seem to have any effect.

I also have tried `-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.6px;` this actually helps on some of the edges but causes aliasing on other edges.

Apart from resorting to an SVG graphic in place of the text (for this particular case), do any of you know any solutions?

Edit:

All relevant font css:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'robotoregular';
        src: url('roboto-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('roboto-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('roboto-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    * {
        font-family: 'robotoregular', Arial, Sans-Serif;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 130px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add to the question more `@font-face` code in your .css file? Maybe there's the problem.

Comment: @SylwesterPilarz I've added the CSS used for the font at the end of the original post.

Comment: Did you try to add this font by `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');`?

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't improve on the problem at all. Kinda wondering if at this point its just chromes fault and there's nothing that can be done...

Comment: are you using some special version of roboto? have you tried to test with https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto ?

Comment: I've tried all the different font versions of roboto(light, regular, bold, etc) from there cdn directly. None of them seem to work. The version in the photo above was a version of regular that I compressed but the uncompressed version looks identical(displaying the same blurred edges/ rounded corners). Edit: The font looks exceptionally crispy on Chrome on mobile devices so I don't think its the fonts fault.

Comment: I read that each browser have its own image rendering, so maybe there is no appropriate answer.

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing, just wanted to run it by a design community first to see if anyone had magic answer that would fix it lol. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: I just tested Firefox and Chrome with Roboto from google fonts, the differences are insignificant with perhaps a little more anti-aliasing in Chrome, but there is nothing I would call a problem. All browsers render fonts slightly differently, and so it's totally unsurprising.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is no answer at this time, it appears to just be a problem with Google Chrome (on Windows, not sure about Mac OS). The only solution is to wait for Google to fix it.

(unless one of you know some amazing way of overcoming this, in that case please reply with it :D)

Comment: No, its probably the hinting of the font. But yes you dont actually have full control of the rendering engine, each browser will look different for the foreseable future.

Comment: Most likely different methods of anti-aliasing the text.